# Why doesn't ElasticFox support Micro instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have found that using ElasticFox, I can only launch Large+ EC2 instances, while through Amazon Web Console I can launch smaller instances. Any idea why this is the case? Where do I report this bug/feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [project home](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/609?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) on amazon, it looks like it was last updated on 01 Sep 2010. Thats before micro instances were [announced](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/09/new-amazon-ec2-micro-instances.html) on 9 Sep 2010 and hence the reason(probably) for not supporting them.

The [project home on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elasticfox/) is probably the best place to request this feature or I guess you could get hold of the source code and do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as stated by Geoff Appleford, Elasticfox is an outdated extension. I dont know why it's development stopped as it is a great tool.

If you wish to do things that are achieved through Elasticfox, I would suggest you to take a look at Hybridfox. Hybrdifox is a fork of Elasticfox which supports other private clouds as well. It is also a great tool too.

It is also open source and actively updated. Check it's project home(http://code.google.com/p/hybridfox/)

Sources:
[Hybridfox home](http://code.google.com/p/hybridfox/)